# "Delegating uninstallation of assembly file X to Fusion" What does that mean?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm currently trying to find out why some component is not removed from the system after uninstall. When executing the installer with verbose logging, I find this message in the uninstall log:

> delegating uninstallation of assembly
>   file : ATL80.dll to Fusion

I'm trying to find out what that means. What is Fusion and why is the removal of the file being delegated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fusion* is a library that manages assemblies in *Global Assembly Cache*. To install and to remove assemblies from GAC, a Custom Action is used.

The file could be left unremoved because it is used by another application.

Comment: @Dave Because it is: not _managed_ but _side-by-side_ assembly. Isn't it installed into `C:\Windows\WinSxS` subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's still not managed though. Also, it doesn't get removed, which is what I'm investigating. There are other versions of the same in WinSxS as well, so there shouldn't be any other client to use it.

Comment: Had this particular version of the assembly existed when you installed your app? I understand it is hard to figure that out. Another option I could suggest is to test it on a clean machine. And I know that libs installed with vcredist.exe do not get removed for some reason when you uninstall it from Control Panel.

Comment: I'm using a VM to test our installer for certification. No, this particular version is not present before the install, but another version is. After uninstall, this particular version does not get removed. We don't use vcredist, but a merge module. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. We use merge module for msvcrt80.dll, it gets removed with our product. Maybe install log could shed more light on the issue.